# Rails Active model serializer returns array instead of json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I am using Rails to create APIs containing basic todo information: name, list, and items. I want it to return json format, to look something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "JSON API is awesome!",
        "body": "You should be using JSON API",
        "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
        "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "href": "http://example.com/api/posts",
    "meta": {
      "count": 10
    }
  }
}
```

*^code from [Active Serializer's Github](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md).*

When I look on my localhost http://localhost:3000/api/users/, it shows

`[{"id":1,"username":"Iggy1","items":[{"id":1,"list_id":1,"name":"Wash dishes","completed":true},{"id":7,"list_id":1,"name":"Finish this assignment","completed":false}],"lists":[{"id":1,"name":"Important!","user_id":1,"permission":"private"},...`

It is returning an array of hashes. I am sure I missed an important step when I was setting up my serializer. How can I reformat my array of hashes into JSON API format?

I've read [getting started guide](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md), [rendering](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md), and [JSON API](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/jsonapi/schema.md) section but I still couldn't figure it out. I might have overlooked it.

Some of my codes:

*app/serializers/user_serializer.rb*

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :username#, :email
   has_many :items, through: :lists
   has_many :lists
end
```

*app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb*

```
   def index
     @users = User.all
     render json: @users, each_serializer: UserSerializer
   end
```

*routes*
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do

     resources :users do
       resources :lists
     end
  end
end
```

Let me know if I can clarify it better. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you declared you want to use the JSON API adapter? Need to set `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi` in your config.  Instructions [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md#jsonapi)

Comment: It worked! Thank you :). I didn't know where to put it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer from comments)

To use the JSON API adapter, you need to declare you want to use it.

```
 ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi
```

As per the AMS [readme](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md#jsonapi).

Comment: Read Me link is currently broken, this might help: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api # Default: `:attributes`
```

from [0-10-stable documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable#high-level-behavior)

However, this did not solve my problem.  It was due to the Hash being nested as discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32079897/7573223)