# Rails ActiveModel Serializer : Retrieving Deeply Nested ActiveRecord Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm using **ActiveModel::Serializer** to serialize my json data.
I have three models as follows

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoiceDetails, inverse_of: :invoice
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoiceDetails
end

class InvoiceDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoice_details
end
```

**The serializers are as follows :**

```
class InvoiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :total_amount, :balance_amount, :created_at
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :invoiceDetails
end


class InvoiceDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :quantity
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :mrp, :sp, :cp, :stocks, :isPublished
  has_one :category
end
```

**When I retrieve an invoice I get the attributes from the associated invoiceDetails model and customer model but the attributes from the product model associated with the invoiceDetails model are missing.**

For example if I retrieve an invoice, this is the output :

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "total_amount": 450,
        "balance_amount": 350,
        "created_at": "2017-06-27T17:02:20.000Z",
        "customer": {
            "id": 4,
            "company_id": 1,
            "name": "vivek",
            "isActive": true,
            "created_at": "2017-06-27T14:35:50.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-06-27T14:35:50.000Z",
            "mobile": "12345678",
            "address": "test",
            "pan_number": null,
            "tin_number": null,
            "party_name": "vipul jwelers"
        },
        "invoiceDetails": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**However if I retrieve invoiceDetail directly I get the associated model attributes.**

```
**[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "quantity": 5,
        "product": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Test Prod",
            "mrp": 150,
            "sp": 130,
            "cp": 100,
            "stocks": 100,
            "isPublished": true
        },
        "invoice": {
            "id": 4,
            "total_amount": 3903,
            "balance_amount": 3,
            "created_at": "2017-07-01T07:45:02.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "quantity": 10,
        "product": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Test Prod 2",
            "mrp": 300,
            "sp": 250,
            "cp": 200,
            "stocks": 10,
            "isPublished": true
        },
        "invoice": {
            "id": 4,
            "total_amount": 3903,
            "balance_amount": 3,
            "created_at": "2017-07-01T07:45:02.000Z"
        }
    }
]**
```

So for retrieving the nested attributes directly from invoice, do I need to change the relationship among my models?

Has someone encountered the same problems, or any work around you can suggest?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079897/serializing-deeply-nested-associations-with-active-model-serializers

Comment: Only I can add: don't use it globally, use `render json: data, include: '**'` where you actually need deep nesting.

Comment: Thanks man that worked..!!

Comment: Can you add an answer to your question or comment here what you have to do for others that might have the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

If someone is stuck over this problem, here is what I did :

Whenever I want to retrieve the deeply nested association I add the **"include **" keyword** in the controller during response.

For example :

```
def show
    cust_id = params[:customer_id]
    invoice_id = params[:id]
    if cust_id && invoice_id
      invoice = Invoice.where(:id => invoice_id, :customer_id => cust_id)
      render json: invoice, include: '**', status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: "Customer ID or Invoice ID is NULL" }, status: 422
    end
  end
```

The **include * ***  will retrieve all the nested attributes for the invoice model using the serializer if defined for the respective models.

Comment: Couldn't edit your answer due to char limit but might want to update your text to reflect `include **` instead of `include *` to match your code block

Comment: I had to remove the ```belongs_to``` statements in the serializers others I saw a 'stack too deep' error.