# How to return a response from rails api with ActiveRecord relations 2 levels deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating a Rails api for teachers to rank students based on certain criteria.  I have four models: classroom, student, criterion and rank.

- Students/Criteria are many to many through Rank
- Students/Classroom are many to many
- Rank is a join table between Student/Criteria with the additional field of rank, which is an integer between 1-4.

I am able to return the list of Students belonging to a Classroom in a response (1 relation deep) by allowing Classroom.students through in my classroom serializer.  How can I return each student's ranks nested within students in my Classroom response (2 relations deep) from my API?  Ideal response as below:

Classroom_A:

```
{
  id: "123",
  name: "classroom A",
  students: [
    { id: "456"
      name: Juanita,
      gender: female,
      ranks: [
        { id: "789",
          student_id: "456",
          name: "willingness to help others",
          rank: "4"
         },
         { id: "101",
          student_id: "456",
          name: "Leadership",
          rank: "3"
         } ...
       ]
    },
    { id: "232"
      name: Billy,
      gender: male,
      ranks: [
        { id: "789",
          student_id: "232",
          name: "willingness to help others",
          rank: "3"
         },
         { id: "101",
          student_id: "232",
          name: "Leadership",
          rank: "3"
         } ...
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079897/rails-serializing-deeply-nested-associations-with-active-model-serializers

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was posted at [Rails: Serializing deeply nested associations with active_model_serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079897/rails-serializing-deeply-nested-associations-with-active-model-serializers) (thanks for the link @lam Phan)

However, the most upvoted answer for that post was not super clear and there was no code example. Super dissapointing.  I also looked into the JsonApi adapter and was not able to get the solution I was looking for.  In the end I ended up taking the same route as the OP for the linked question: in the serializer I wrote my own function and manually sideloaded the other data that I wanted.  I was hoping to do this the "Rails way" but in the end I chose to just get it done.

```
class ClassroomSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :school_name, :students

  def students
    customized_students = []

    object.students.each do |student|
      custom_student = student.attributes
      custom_student['ranks'] = student.student_ranks
      customized_students.push(custom_student)
    end
    customized_students
  end
end
```